# Paypal sandbox account approver url only showing one option?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

When redirecting to paypal approval url, I am only seeing one option i.e. return to merchant. I am using my sandbox account. The link "return to merchant" is redircting to my cancel_url instead of return_url.
Please help. I am using paypal rest sdk .

I have zero balance in my paypal account.

[image]

Comment: can you paste the JSON request/response?

Comment: I was able to make paypal working by using django-paypal. when redirecting to approval url , I get above page and url says expresscheckout generic error: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-25T0801620213664S#/checkout/genericError?code=VU5TVVBQT1JURURfUEFZRUVfQ1VSUkVOQ1k%3D

Comment: It's going to be hard to debug unless it's clear what request is being logged

Comment: can that genericError code give you some hint what caused this ? usually every errorCode gives you exact error cause in api development.